# Import template in typescript without require

Tags: angularjs, typescript, import, ecmascript-6

I am using typescript with angular 1.5 component. And I have a custom designed decorator where I send template via require. It works except I get a tslint warning. (I don't want to turn off this rule)

> require() style import is forbidden

Here is my component

```
import './main.template.html';

const app: ng.IModule = angular.module('app');
@Component(app, {
  selector: 'mainComponent',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  styleUrls: '',
  template: require('./main.template.html')
})
class MainComponent extends BaseComponent {
   constructor() {
     super();
   }
}
```

Here is my decorator

```
export const Component = function(module: ng.IModule, options: {
  selector: string,
  controllerAs?: string,
  styleUrls?: string,
  template?: string,
  templateUrl?: string
}) {
return (controller: Function) => {
   module.component(options.selector, angular.extend(options, {  controller: controller }));
  };
};
```

I have tried to pass templateUrl instead of template and i get run time error of file not found.

I have also tried to import template as variable and it gives compile time error and looks like it's not supported.

```
import mytemplate: string from './main.template.html';
```

I am using webpack. Hence, can't use absolute path from the root.

Do you have any idea how to import template in typescript without using require.

Comment: can you show error while importing template

Answer (score 2):

For templateUrl error , check your reference and directory structure.

Or , insert html data inside template :-

```
@Component(app, {
selector: 'mainComponent',
controllerAs: 'ctrl',
styleUrls: '',
template: `<div>//content
           </div>`
})
```

Comment: I am using webpack build and hence there is no template file or directory structure.

Comment: put your template in same directory as webpack build.js , maybe templateUrl refer file from directory origin of your build.js

Comment: This will work. However, I have to put all the template (for each component in a directory). My concern is, this might not be best practice while using webpack as a build tool